# constructor value does not assign to another value why explain

Tags: state, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

[I think It,s an error][1]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract MAth{

    uint public publicM;

    constructor()  {
        publicM = 10;
    }
    uint public remPublic = publicM;
    
}
```

when I assign my constructor value to another variable it does not show I do not understand how it,s possible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign global variable to a variable globally. you need to do it inside a function because to update a state variable you need to send a transaction:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract MAth{

uint public publicM;
uint public remPublic;

  constructor()  {
    publicM = 10;
  }
  function setRemPublic() public  returns(uint)  {
   remPublic = publicM;
   return remPublic;
  }
}
```

Call `setRemPublic` first and then click on `remPublic`

[image]